# Monitoring C# Threads - Which does what/when

Tags: c#, multithreading

As everybody, I am used to debugging my code in VS in step-by-step mode. Well, now that I have an application with many Background Workers everywhere, I am not in Kansas anymore.

What is the most efficient way to debug threaded applications and be able to monitor each and every thread to keep track of what's happening all over the code?

As of now, I stick to good ol' debugging using separate logger instances for each Thread, but this is slowly becoming a nightmare and I'll soon be drowning into my own logs.

Comment: Yes, the difficulty of getting multi-threaded code right is at least O(n^3).  It approaches O(n!) when you didn't know what kind of trouble you can get into when you got started.  The only solution is to keep n small.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't try to debug everything all at once.  Narrow your focus to a particular behavior in one thread or pair of threads that interact around some mutex lock.  If accessing a shared resource is the problem, set breakpoints around use of that resource (which should be in common code, not all over the place).

If you just want to see that thread 3 completed before thread 1, or that thread 2 used up all its work items and is sitting idle, use logs for that.

You can also use the VS Threads view to see what each thread is doing whenever the process is stopped at any breakpoint on any thread.  This can give you some insight into what all the threads are doing at any given instant.

Comment: I have shared Queues between threads (some are queuing, others dequeuing). How to debug a particular thread when it is instantiated from the same Thread class and Run several times at a row (using GetThreadID for example) ?

Comment: AHA ! The Famous VS Threads Window, of course ! Last Time I used it was in college. So painful experience I wiped it off my memory :-) Guess I'm gonna use it again though... Thanx !

Comment: I seem to recall that you can associate a name with a thread, too.  I don't recall the details, but something you might search for.

Answer (score 5):

A small tip that might ease your pain is to use Visual Studio to freeze threads that you are not interested in. Then when you tell the debugger to continue, the frozen threads will never execute and will not hit breakpoints and confuse you.

Maybe you can use this method to allow only the threads you are debugging to work. E.g. keep one thread that enqueues and one thread that dequeues active, but freeze everything else.

You can freeze/thaw threads from Visual Studio's Threads window, by right-clicking on a thread.

Comment: Very Educative indeed. Did not know that feature (I lived in Kansas for a very long time) :-) VERY Useful. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Write it correctly the first time.

Joking aside, the trick to debugging is to break it down into manageable parts. Tackle one worker task at a time, make absolutely sure it does what it's supposed to.

Once you've done that, debugging issues in the main thread is a lot easier, because you can pretty much ignore the background workers and just presume they're yielding correct results when they should be.

The only place left that's harder to debug than a single-threaded application is the interconnect between the threads, which shouldn't be much more difficult if you're using the libraries the way you should be.

Comment: The fact is, I WAS pretty sure of my code (already tested threads one by one and together too, with success). But as of now, my app strangely began to behave in a weird way (not responding, falling in an endless loop because of waiting for a thread to send a message) I am trying to get into that thread by debugging it but as it is instantiated many times I get dropped of that particular thread while debugging. I am confused...

Comment: In this specific case, what you want to do is pause every thread. All of them. Then you can wake up the specific thread that's supposed to be sending the message, and step through it to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, right, you described my intimate desire. Now, Can you tell me exactly how to do it ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I Stumbled upon a detailed MSDN article about [Debugging Multithreaded Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164746.aspx)
wich was of great help. Thanx for all the previous answers that guided me towards the right track.