# Handle Queue faster

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, queue

I have a queue , it receives data overtime. 
I used multi thread to dequeue and save to database.
I create an Array of Thread to do this job.

```
for (int i = 0; i < thr.Length; i++)
{
    thr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SaveData));
    thr[i].Start();
}
```

SaveData

Note : eQ and eiQ is 2 global queue. I used while to keep thread alive.

```
public void SaveData()
{

    var imgDAO = new imageDAO ();
    string exception = "";
    try
    {
        while (eQ.Count > 0 && eiQ.Count > 0)
        {
            var newRecord = eQ.Dequeue();
            var newRecordImage = eiQ.Dequeue();                        

            imageDAO.SaveEvent(newEvent, newEventImage);

            var storepath = Properties.Settings.Default.StorePath;
            save.WriteFile(storepath, newEvent, newEventImage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {                
        Global._logger.Info(e.Message + e.Source);
    }
}
```

It did create multi thread but when I debug, only 1 thread alive, the rest is dead.
I dont know why ? Any one have idea? Tks

Comment: May be `SaveData` runs faster than new thread starts?

Comment: Can you show your thread function? Are you using SQLServer, or other database?

Comment: Update SaveData method. I used Entity Framework

Comment: Aside from anything else, it looks like you've got race conditions...

Comment: I new an array of thread[4] all of them start is null so thr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SaveData));
                            thr[i].Start(); to create thread

Comment: How do you know that only 1 thread alive when debugging?

Comment: OK. Now i got it. Maybe create some counter to check how many times these threads fired, to check that Hamlet Hakobyan idea with threads running faster than starting new one.

Comment: @Thinhbk : I just check a point in main code and check properties of each thread in Array, there's value IsAlive

Comment: I suspect that it's not the correct way to check, you may use log to know which thread is calling your method. You may refer this answer for debugging multi-threading app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329528/monitoring-c-sharp-threads-which-does-what-when

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `WriteFile` in that thread function.

Is this possible, that you trying to write file that may be locked by another thread (same filename or something)?

And one more thing - saving data on disk by multiple threads - i dont like it.

I think you should create some buffer instead of many threads and write it every few records/entries.

Comment: Or pass on the events to be written to another queue!

Comment: Each record store an Image, Method WriteFile is used to write 100 images to a special file. So the exception occured when multi thread try to write image to a same file at the sametime. I think this maybe the reason that thread is dead

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your threads will only live as long as there are elements in the queues, as soons as both are emptied the threads will terminate. This could explain why you see only one living thread while debugging.

A potential answer to you question would be to use a BlockingCollection from the [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) classes instead of a Queue. That has the capability of doing a blocking dequeue, which will stop the thread(s) until more elements are available for processing.

Another problem is the nice race condition between *eQ* and *eiQ* -- consider using a single queue with a Tuple or custom data type so you can dequeue both *newRecord* and *newRecordImage* in a single operation.

Comment: My queue increase so fast, about 1000/12s. SO there's no chance queue run out of element.

Comment: Ah, then you definitely should take care of the race condition!